# Avoid label overlap python igraph

Tags: python, overlap, igraph

I'm using python igraph and many of my charts are plotted with pesky overlapping labels. I found an rpackage solution in this thread ([Plotting clusters of nominal data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378910/plotting-clusters-of-nominal-data-in-r/17380908#17380908)) but that is for R Package. Here is an example of what I'm getting. The python documentation doesn't mention how to troubleshoot this. Appreciate any insight.

[image: overlap]

Comment: similarly to R solution that you posted, you can use : 
`spanning_tree(self, weights=None, return_tree=True) `See also the documentation [link](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#spanning_tree)